# AWS Amplify Graphql Creating a new User table, necessary?

Tags: aws-lambda, graphql, amazon-dynamodb, aws-amplify, aws-amplify-cli

I'm fairly new to Amplify and been playing around with it for a couple of weeks now. I've been incorporating it into Next.js, which is pretty nice.

I originally created a new User table/record using lambda function: after a user signs up and confirms their email, it should automatically create a new record in the User table with some information. I only did this because I thought Amplify only provided a few attributes, but until recently I found out that you can pretty much create custom attributes.

So, because of this, would there be an argument to create another User table? I would like to know how people are handling User information in big applications.

I guess one thing I can think of is making relationships with other tables. I haven't gone too far into figuring this out, but is it possible to still make connections if I don't have User table in my graphql schema?

Answer (score 0):

Yes I have the same issue and was thinking to have a Users table where I enable owner authorization. This Owner-based authorization allows you to tie a data record to a user. Owners can read, create, update, and delete the record.

Allow the owner to perform these operations on their own records:

Create

Read

Update

Delete